# How do I count the number of times a string appears in a column?

Tags: awk

I have text files with 3 columns and I want to count the the number of each string appears in column 2.

The second column of file1:

```
SAM
MATHEW
ALAN
NEELA
JOHN
```

The second column of file2:

```
ALAN
NEELA
KAREEM
MOHA
```

Desired output:

```
SAM-1
MATHEW-1
ALAN-2
NEELA-2
JOHN-1
KAREEM-1
MOHA-1
```

Comment: Is there possible to be more specific? We do not even know what programming language you speak or if it relates to a system database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{a[$2]++}END{for(k in a)print k"-"a[k]}' file1 file2
MOHA-1
NEELA-2
JOHN-1
KAREEM-1
ALAN-2
MATHEW-1
SAM-1
```

Answer (score 1):

This would accomplish it, although the output is unordered:

```
awk '{ h[$2]++ } END { for(k in h) print k " - " h[k] }' file1 file2
```

A tally is kept in the `h` associative array, and when all files have been processed the results are printed in the `END` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[$2]++;next}END{for(i in a)print i"-"a[i]}' file1 file2
```

tested:

```
> cat file1
10993   item    0
11002   item    6
693661  item    7
> cat file2
10993   item    0
11002   item1   6
693661  item2   7
> awk '{a[$2]++;next}END{for(i in a)print i"-"a[i]}' file1 file2
item1-1
item2-1
item-4
>
```

Comment: `;next` does nothing in this case.